# MPMoviePlayerController is not working while allocating it again

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have two View controllers, in the firstViewController i wrote the code for MPMoviePlayerController and in the secondViewController also i wrote the same Code . then, only one MPMoviePlayerController is showing Video, But the other one is showing Black Screen.Even i Created one instance of MPMoviePlayerController for the both ViewController but Still did not work for me.

Here is the sample Code:

```
 myPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[myPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 393)]; 
myPlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
myPlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone;
myPlayer.fullscreen = YES;
myPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
myPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
myPlayer.contentURL =theurl;
[self.view addSubview:myPlayer.view];
```

Please tell me, How to Play Video in both View Controllers?

Thank in Advance

Comment: What iOS are you targeting and how is the my Player property set up (strong?)?

Comment: @BlueVoodoo, I am using iOS4 and iOS5 also. i wrote the code with property(retain) and only declaration with out property also.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be, you should create a Video view controller that plays videos and that can be called whenever required.